# How to turn off tab opening on execution in VSC?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With a recent update, every time I run code the "Julia" icon opens up on the activity bar. What settings control this behavior? If there isn't a setting, is there a workaround to prevent it?

Version: 1.57.0 
Commit: b4c1bd0a9b03c749ea011b06c6d2676c8091a70c 
OS: Darwin x64 20.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Configure your Julia Extension to prevent the "Julia" icon from opening up on the activity bar.

More information on how to do this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_configuring-extensions